# What does ||= actually do in controller before_action?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In rails controller code I mostly see something like below:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_user

  def some_action
  end

  private

  def set_user
    @user ||= User.find params[:id]
  end
end
```

So, I would actually like to know that,

i) What does ||= do?
ii) What are it's use cases? and,
iii) mainly, Is doing

```
@user ||= User.find params[:id]
```

means that @user object is persisted between the http requests?

Comment: iii) No, [each request makes a new controller instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14172986/why-does-rails-create-a-controller-for-every-request), so `@user` is not persisted.

Comment: To give a clear answer: Here the `||=` doesn't make any sense unless you call `set_user` multiple times during the _same_ request.